# Material ui popover how to anchor to another element (different from event target)

Tags: reactjs, reference, material-ui

Well typically when we use popover we set the anchor during a mouse event to `event.currentTarget`.

However this is impossible in certain situations and undesired in others. - How can I set the popover anchor element directly?

```
import React from "react";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  function handleClick(event) {
    //setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setAnchorEl(); //How to refer to the div?
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography>Anchor point of popover here</Typography>
      <Button aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Typography>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-1fbgf)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a ref to get at whichever element you want to use as the anchor. The example below uses `spanRef` to get at the element rendered by the `Typography` element.

The placement of the `Popover` relative to the anchor element is then dependent on the `anchorOrigin` and `transformOrigin` properties. In the example below, the top-left corner of the `Popover` will be aligned with the bottom-right corner of the span. I changed the component of the `Typography` from the default `<p>` element to `<span>` to make the positioning easier to see. Since block elements (such as `<p>`) have 100% width by default even if the contents don't take up much of that space, the `Popover` can appear to be far away from the anchor if the anchor element is much wider than is visually apparent.

```
import React from "react";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const spanRef = React.useRef();
  function handleClick() {
    setAnchorEl(spanRef.current);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography component="span" ref={spanRef}>
        Anchor point of popover here
      </Typography>
      <br />
      <Button aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "right"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
      >
        <Typography>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Use ref for anchorEl]

Comment: Small change to open automatically the Popover https://codesandbox.io/s/use-ref-for-anchorel-forked-ou7eo?file=/demo.js

Comment: Why do you go through the trouble of setting the id to 'undefined'?  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: @lowcrawler That was just carried forward from the code in the original question. I can’t think of any particular reason for it.

Comment: Just a side note, in your example the dropdown opens way far away from anchor, that is the behaviour that i'm currently trying to fix in my project but no clue

although the first comment seems to be fixing it, any idea?

Comment: @amdev I've updated my example and added some explanation of how the anchor works. Ricardo's example "fixes" the behavior by using the button element as the anchor. I was previously using the `<div>` as the anchor. Since the div had 100% width and the popover was aligned with the bottom-center of it, it looked "far away" from the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small variation from Ryan Cogswell example to open automatically the Popover:

https://codesandbox.io/s/use-ref-for-anchorel-forked-ou7eo

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function SimplePopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const divRef = React.useRef();
  function handleClick() {
    setAnchorEl(divRef.current);
  }

  function handleClose() {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setAnchorEl(divRef.current);
  }, [divRef]);

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography>Anchor point of popover here</Typography>
      <Button
        ref={divRef}
        aria-describedby={id}
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "center"
        }}
      >
        <Typography>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
    </div>
  );
}
```